# Chinese Rare Character Mapping from UTF8 to BIG5 in JAVA

Tags: java

> byte[] byteArr1 = {(byte)0x8E,(byte)0x62};

Byte Array consist of Bytes of Rare Chinese Character in BIG5.

> String out = new String(byteArr1, "ISO-8859-1");

Here I am assigning bytes to my string variable by translating its encoding to ISO-8859-1.
But after assigning my hex value changes from (8E 62) to (3F 62). Due to which my out string changes.

Thank You In advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)?

The encoding you provide when creating a String must be that of the underlying byte array. You are always converting from something to Unicode. In your case you should try `"Big5"` instead of `"ISO-8859-1"`

Java Strings are always unicode (String class is UTF-16) and therefore copepage free.